# How do you write a Microsoft Access query that outputs the frequency of elements in a field as a percentage?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking to create a query in Microsoft Access that when run will count the unique elements in a field and output these values as a percentage of the total number of elements.

For example if I had the table SampleTable with the following field of 8 elements:

LetterValue

z

x

x

x

y

x

z

y

I am looking for an output that returns the following

LetterValue    Percent

x            50%

y            25%

z            25%

Even better, is it possible to modify this simple count query to get this result?

```
SELECT LetterValue, COUNT(*) AS QTY
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY LetterValue;
```

Comment: Well, you have the count for each letter value...so get the total number of letters, and you essentially have the percentages.

Comment: Sadly, I do not know how to do this in MS Access, but the function you're looking for is **pivot**. Maybe that helps

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but unfortunately I was specifically told to output the percentages in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several parts to this question, including converting the value to a string (so you can append a '%'):

```
SELECT st.LetterValue, cdbl(100.0*COUNT(*)/tot.tot)&'%' AS QTY
FROM SampleTable st,
     (select COUNT(*) as tot
      from SampleTable
     ) as tot
GROUP BY st.LetterValue, tot.tot;
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that while my example has 8 values, the table which I will apply this to has over 1000000 values, is there a way I can do this without imputing the table values every time I run it?

Comment: @Calle This query isn't specific to your problem, it would work if you had 2 values or a million values. But Gordon, maybe your typo is confusing him. `tot.to` Is probably asking him to enter a parameter. It should be `tot.tot`.

Comment: And now it works just fine, of course I need to change the sig figs, but that's easy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this also

```
SELECT group_counts.letter, group_counts.countNums, (group_counts.countNums/total_count.total_nums*100) AS [Percent]
  FROM (SELECT letter, Count(*) AS countNums FROM [yourTable] GROUP BY letter) AS group_counts, 
       (SELECT Count(*) AS total_nums FROM [yourTable]) AS total_count;
```

This will output like

```
Letter     CountNums     Percent
 a         2             20
 b         4             40
 c         2             20
 d         1             10
 e         1             10
```